# The type or namespace named "Bank"cannot be found (are your missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D6qy.png)I want to create the unit test to the Bank class which is under Lab2 namespace.

I don't know what is the problem here. I added the reference. The frameworks are the same. But still it is not possible to use Bank class.
I also added
using Lab2;
What am I missing or doing incorrectly? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnQnK.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aLFV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjyxe.png)

Comment: Please show the Bank class too (including namespace).

Comment: added the screenshot:) thanks!!

Comment: Please edit your code into the question as text. You can't compile a screenshot.

Comment: Take `Bank` class to a new file or out of `Program` class.

Comment: Thank you:) You helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the `Bank` class inside of the `Program` class. You also put the `Main()` method in that nested `Bank` class. Instead, put the `Bank` class in its own file such as Bank.cs.

**Bank.cs**

```c#
namespace Lab2
{
    public class Bank2
    {
        // Class definition
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```c#
namespace Lab2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bank bank = new Bank();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the `Bank` class as a nested class inside the `Program` class.

Therefore you need to reference it by the scoped name `Program.Bank`.

You probably don't want to nest it (your `Main` method is now inside the `Bank` class too), so could move the definition of `Bank` outside of the `Program` class, then your tests should work as they are.